# No known conversions

Tags: c++

I'm have a problem with my constructors.

I get the following error:

> no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘`std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*`’ to ‘`std::multiset<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >}`’
>
> multiset.cpp:47:1: note: candidate: `my_multiset::iterator::iterator()
>    my_multiset::iterator::iterator(void){}`
>
> multiset.h:17:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘`std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*`’ to ‘`const cpt323::my_multiset::iterator&`’
>   multiset.h:17:10: note: candidate: `constexpr my_multiset::iterator::iterator(cpt323::my_multiset::iterator&&)`
>   multiset.h:17:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘`std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >*`’ to ‘`my_multiset::iterator&&`’

The code is working with the exception of this part, any suggestion on how to make the appropriate changes

```cpp
class my_multiset : custom_datastructure
{
   std::multiset<std::string> the_set;
   std::multiset<std::string>::iterator head;
   std::multiset<std::string>::iterator tail;

public:
   class iterator : public custom_datastructure::iterator
   {
      std::multiset<std::string>::iterator current;

   public:
      iterator(void){};
      iterator(std::multiset<std::string>::iterator a_set) : current(a_set)
      {
      }

   };

   multiset(void);
   std::unique_ptr<custom_datastructure::iterator> begin(void)
   {
      head = the_set.begin();
      return std::make_unique<my_multiset::iterator>(&head);
   }

   std::unique_ptr<custom_datastructure::iterator> end(void)
   {
      tail = the_set.end();
      return std::make_unique<my_multiset::iterator>(&tail);
   }
}
```

custom_datastructure is as below

```
struct datastructure
{
    struct iterator
    {
        /** OPERATORS HERE **/ 
        virtual std::unique_ptr<datastructure::iterator> operator++(void) = 0;
       /** ETC **/
    };
    virtual std::unique_ptr<iterator> begin(void) = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<iterator> end(void) = 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at the type your `iterator` constructor wants.  What type is `&head`, that you're passing it?

Comment: What's the purpose of `my_multiset`?  I see no real value in it, or at least, there is probably a much better way of accomplishing what you're trying to accomplish.  Are we getting close to [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) territory?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm head is ```std::multiset<std::string>::iterator``` and the constructor takes ```std::multiset<std::string>::iterator``` to the best of my understanding.

Comment: @JeJo Sure Ill add it

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the purpose is to practise inheritance, that is all. There is so realy world value in doing this.

Comment: @Koax Actually you're learning when *not* to use inheritance.

Comment: But you're not passing `head`, you're passing `&head`.  So what type are you passing?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Reference to head?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ill take that up with the tutor.

Comment: @Koax -- The `&` in this context does not mean reference.  It means `address-of`.  It is just a coincidence that reference and address-of use the same symbol, but mean different things.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've just assumed they are essentially the same thing, different wording for the same thing. I'll have to do some more reading. 

I've removed &head and replaced with head. still returns the same error though.

Comment: The `(void)` parameter list is a C-ism that you don't need. In C++, `()` is equivalent and easier on the eye.

Comment: Shouldn't `my_multiset::iterator` derive from `custom_datastructure::iterator` instead of `custom_datastructure`?

Comment: @Koax No, reference and address-of are not the same thing.  They are not even related.  A reference in C++ has a specific meaning -- the address-of has a specific meaning.  I know the word "reference" is used informally in other computer languages, but in C++, a reference has a well-defined, formal meaning.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, it should and it does in the actual code. I seem to have edited that out.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it looks like I have some reading up to do.

Comment: I have a general case solution that should work pretty well for you

Answer (score 0):

## Why is your code breaking?

The reason your code breaks is because `unique_ptr` can't be used as an iterator, so if you wrap your iterator in a `unique_ptr` when returning it from `begin()` and `end()`, then it isn't usable as an iterator anymore.

An iterator doesn't have to be a pointer; it just needs to act like one. In addition, an iterator shouldn't own data. A class owns data if the class is responsible for deleting that data, but an iterator shouldn't be responsible for deleting anything. It should just provide a way of accessing the data. This means that iterators can and should be passed around by value (instead of using `std::unique_ptr`).

## How do we fix the design?

So here's the big question: are you trying to create an interface that returns some iterators, or are you trying to create an interface for things that act like iterators?

### Creating an interface that returns some iterators

The most generic way to do this is through templates. The benefit of using templates is that it enables us to re-use this interface in a wide variety of situations, and we can `#include` the interface where we need it, without having any dependencies in the file defining the template.

```
template<class Iterator>
class Iterable {
   public:
    virtual Iterator begin() = 0;
    virtual Iterator end() = 0; 
};
```

We can use this to define `my_multiset` as returning iterators to `std::multiset`:

```
class my_multiset 
  : public Iterable<typename std::multiset<std::string>::iterator>
{
    std::multiset<std::string> the_set;
   public:
    using iterator = typename std::multiset<std::string>::iterator;
    iterator begin() override {
        return the_set.begin(); 
    }
    iterator end() override {
        return the_set.end(); 
    }
};
```

### Creating a `GenericIterator<Value>` - a class that can be assigned any iterator

Because pointers-to-iterators act like pointers, and not the underlying iterator, instead of using a `unique_ptr<BaseIterator>`, we're going to want to create a wrapper class that handles everything for us, while still acting like a normal iterator.

You'll be able to use it just like any old iterator, except that it can be assigned or created with an iterator to anything that derefences to `Value`. That means that the same GenericIterator can bind to a list iterator, a vector iterator, or even a `std::multiset` iterator.

**Example showing how it could be used:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
    std::list<int>   l{10, 20, 30};

    GenericIterator<int&> begin, end;

    begin = v.begin();
    end   = v.end();

    for (; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        std::cout << *begin << " ";
    }

    begin = l.begin();
    end   = l.end();
    for (; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        std::cout << *begin << " ";
    }
}
```

**What parts do we need to make `GenericIterator`?** 
`GenericIterator` is going to store a pointer to a virtual base class. We'll also need a derived class that implements the base for a specific Iter.

**Base class:**

The base class virtualizes the main functions of  an iterator: Increment, Dereference, and equality. It also provides a `clone()` method so that it's possible to make copies of iterators. `close()` comes in handy when writing a `GenericIterator` class that wraps this functionality.

```
template <class Value>
class IteratorBase
{
   public:
    virtual Value         operator*() const                     = 0;
    virtual IteratorBase& operator++()                          = 0;
    virtual bool          operator!=(IteratorBase const&) const = 0;
    virtual bool          operator==(IteratorBase const&) const = 0;

    // We need this function for making copies of the iterator
    virtual IteratorBase* clone() const = 0;
    virtual ~IteratorBase()             = default;
};
```

**Derived class:**
This derived class can wrap basically any other iterator on the planet, and it overrides all the methods in `IteratorBase` to give a fully-functioning iterator.

```
template <class Iter, class Value>
class IteratorDerived : public IteratorBase<Value>
{
    Iter it;

   public:
    IteratorDerived() = default;
    IteratorDerived(Iter it) : it(it) {}
    IteratorDerived(IteratorDerived const&) = default;
    IteratorDerived(IteratorDerived&&)      = default;

    Value                operator*() const override { return *it; }
    IteratorBase<Value>& operator++() override
    {
        ++it;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator!=(IteratorBase<Value> const& other) const override
    {
        auto* derived = dynamic_cast<IteratorDerived const*>(&other);
        return derived == nullptr || it != derived->it;
    }
    bool operator==(IteratorBase<Value> const& other) const override
    {
        auto* derived = dynamic_cast<IteratorDerived const*>(&other);
        return derived != nullptr && it == derived->it;
    }
    IteratorBase<Value>* clone() const override
    {
        return new IteratorDerived(*this);
    }
};
```

**Generic Wrapper:**
This `GenericWrapper` encapsulates all the functionality of an iterator, and because of how we're writing it, you can automatically assign any iterator that deferences to a matching value type.

```
template <class Value>
class GenericIterator
{
    std::unique_ptr<IteratorBase<Value>> iterator;

   public:
    GenericIterator() = default;
    GenericIterator(GenericIterator const& it) : iterator(it.iterator->clone())
    {
    }
    GenericIterator(GenericIterator&&) = default;

    // Creates a GenericIterator from an IteratorBase
    explicit GenericIterator(IteratorBase<Value> const& it)
      : iterator(it.clone())
    {
    }

    // Creates a GenericIterator from an IteratorDerived
    template <class Iter>
    explicit GenericIterator(IteratorDerived<Iter, Value> const& it)
      : iterator(it.clone())
    {
    }

    // Creates a GenericIterator by wrapping another Iter
    template <class Iter>
    GenericIterator(Iter it) : iterator(new IteratorDerived<Iter, Value>(it))
    {
    }

    GenericIterator& operator=(GenericIterator const& it)
    {
        iterator = std::unique_ptr<IteratorBase<Value>>(it.iterator->clone());
        return *this;
    }
    GenericIterator& operator=(GenericIterator&&) = default;

    Value            operator*() const { return *(*iterator); }
    GenericIterator& operator++()
    {
        ++(*iterator);
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator==(GenericIterator const& other) const
    {
        return *iterator == *other.iterator;
    }
    bool operator!=(GenericIterator const& other) const
    {
        return *iterator != *other.iterator;
    }
};
```

**Optional: C++17 template deduction guide**
We can write a template type deduction guide for `GenericIterator` that automatically fills in the correct template parameter, making it easy to wrap any other iterator.

```
template<class Iter>
GenericIterator(Iter) -> GenericIterator<decltype(*std::declval<Iter>())>;
```

Comment: Thank you for putting such effort into you're answer, I truley appretiate the effort you have put into this. However, I'm sorry to say that the answer, for my uses anyway are not usable as it falls out of scope of the requirements, I hope somebody else who stubbles upon this will find it helpful. 

Secondly I think I should point out. That class ```iterator : public custom_datastructure::iterator { }``` isnt actually an iterator, just an object that contains an iterator and to my understanding can be modified even if it is a unique_ptr. I have working examples of just this for a custom list.

Comment: The original question didn’t have any context regarding the project or task you’re working on. What design choices did you have to make that resulted in naming it `iterator` even though it’s not an iterator, and why is it being returned from begin() and end() as though it were an iterator?