# c++ conditional uni-directional iterator

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to achieve something like the pseudo-code below:

```
string foo;  // or vector<int> foo;
auto itr = bar?  foo.begin() : foo.rbegin();
auto end = bar?  foo.end() : foo.rend();
for (  ; itr != end; ++itr) {
// SomeAction ...
}
```

That is, I want to set `itr` to be either a forward iterator or the reverse iterator, depending on some condition `bar`, to scan in forward or reverse direction.

Apparently code like that won't work, since forward iterator and reverse iterator has different type.

Note that I don't want to split into two loops, as those code like `// SomeAction` will be duplicated.

How can I do that?
Answers using C++11 and/or before are preferred.

Also, please elaborate if string and vector have different solutions.

Comment: May be, write a wrapper which contains both iterators (forward and reverse) and a flag which remembers which one is currently used. Additionally, you have to overload at least `operator++()` and `operator!=()`.

Comment: Does some action use/store the iterator apart from dereferencing?

Comment: Is `bar` a compile-time constant?

Comment: @Scheff: Definitely possible, but lots of boilerplate. Even in [C++20](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bataoUAiBgrYAuNi) (and that's an incomplete impl)

Answer (score 27):

I would put the logic in a two-iterator function:

```
<template typename Iter>
void do_stuff(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    for(; first != last; ++first)
    {
        // Do logic
    }
}

bar ? do_stuff(foo.begin(), foo.end()) : do_stuff(foo.rbegin(), foo.rend());
```

Comment: This function should probably be [`std::for_each()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each).

Comment: In simple cases that would definitely be better; I was (for no particular reason) assuming the logic was potentially more complicated where writing out the loop might make it clearer.

Answer (score 17):

The forward and reverse iterators are different types for most if not all containers, so unfortunately if it is a runtime decision, they can not simply be assigned to the same variable through the use of auto.

One option is to move the use of them into a template function:

```
template<class Iterator> void loop(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    for (auto itr = begin; itr != end; ++itr) { ... }
}

if (bar) loop(foo.begin(), foo.end());
else loop(foo.rbegin(), foo.rend());
```

In newer versions of C++ (C++14 and newer, so not C++11) the loop function can be a lambda, by using `auto` as the parameter type.

```
auto loop = [](auto begin, auto end)
{
    for (auto itr = begin; itr != end; ++itr) { ... }
};
```

Another option, although somewhat more involved would be to make a wrapper type that can contain either an iterator or reverse iterator, and acts like an iterator itself with at least the comparison, increment and dereference operators.

Answer (score 9):

> I don't want to split into two loops, as those code like // SomeAction will be duplicated.

Put the action into a lambda.

```
auto lambda = [&](char &val) // `ElementType &`
{
    // ...
};

if (bar)
{
    for (auto &val : foo)
        lambda(val);
}
else
{
    for (auto it = foo.rbegin(); it != foo.rend(); it++)
        lambda(*it);
}
```

---

Alternatively, use indices rather than iterators. This will only work with containers that allow random access.

```
std::size_t i, end, step;
if (bar)
{
    i = 0;
    end = foo.size();
    step = 1;
}
else
{
    i = foo.size() - 1;
    end = -1;
    step = -1;
}

for (; i != end; i += step)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

Comment: Unfortunately, not a C++11 feature as the question was specifically tagged :(

Comment: @FireLancer Forgot it was a C++14 thing, fixed.

Answer (score 9):

One option is to to write a function template for the loop that works with any iterator. Then conditionally call one instance of the template or another. The other answers already show examples of how to do that.

By the way, the loop template might already exist in `<algorithm>` header depending on what you're doing. You could possibly use (but are not limited to) either `std::for_each`, `std::accumulate` or `std::remove` for example:

```
auto body = [captures,needed,by,some,action](char c) {
    // SomeAction ...
};
if (bar)
    std::for_each(foo.begin(),  foo.end(),  body);
else
    std::for_each(foo.rbegin(), foo.rend(), body);
```

If the body of the loop is reusable beyond this context, then you could use a named function as well, but only if you don't need captures. With captures, you can use a named functor type, but that involves quite a bit boilerplate.

---

Another option is to use a type erasing iterator adaptor. It comes with a small runtime cost, and is probably not necessary here. But it is useful to mention in case people have a closely related problem where it is a better fit.

Essentially, such adaptor is to templated iterator what `std::function` is to a templated functor argument. It removes the need for templates, which can be useful for abstract interfaces in particular. Unfortunately though, the standard library doesn't provide such iterator adaptor.

An alterantive for an iterator adaptor is a range adaptor (also not in standard library):

```
using t_erase = boost::adaptors::type_erased<>;
auto range = bar
    ? boost::make_iterator_range(foo.begin(),  foo.end())  | t_erase()
    : boost::make_iterator_range(foo.rbegin(), foo.rend()) | t_erase();
for(char c : range) {
    // SomeAction ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Use an iterator class that abstracts this funtionality.

An iterator has 3 basic functions:

- Increment
- Dereference
- Check for equality

We can use these as guidelines in creating an interface which abstracts this behavior. This interface is a bit cumbersome to use on it's own, but we can use it to build a wrapper class, `GenericIterator`, that can automatically be assigned any other iterator type.

### `GenericIterator`: [A ready-made general purpose solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56120937/4967403)

It's possible to write a `GenericIterator` class that can be assigned iterators from pretty much any collection, including the reverse iterators.

```
int main() {
    bool iterate_forward;
    std::cin >> iterate_forward; 

    std::vector<int> values { 1, 2, 3 };

    GenericIterator<int&> begin, end; 

    if(iterate_forward) {
        begin = values.begin(); 
        end = values.end(); 
    } else {
        begin = values.rbegin();
        end = values.rend(); 
    }

    // Print out the values
    for(; begin != end; ++begin) {
        std::cout << *begin << " ";
    }
}
```

You can download the entirety of the code [from this github repo](https://github.com/jantonioperez/GenericIterator), which I'll be updating and improving as needed.

### Remarks on performance `GenericIterator`

In terms of functionality, `GenericIterator` gives you everything you could possibly ask for. It's light-weight; and it's convenient; and it's easy to re-purpose if your code needs to read from a `std::list` or something other than a vector.

However, due to the fundamental limitations of runtime polymorphism, it's significantly more difficult for the compiler to inline the virtual method calls. This means that `GenericIterator` carries more runtime overhead than other solutions.

It's a good idea to favor static polymorphism and templates over runtime polymorphism when possible. If you're able to do so, use something like [Mark B's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56133707/4967403), which will ultimately be more performant.

### Appendix

**Iterator interface definition.** This class is used to implement `GenericIterator`. A `GenericIterator` contains a pointer to `IteratorBase`, which is used to achieve the runtime polymorphism. Thanks to the `clone()` method, `GenericIterator` remains both copyable and movable as expected.

```
template <class Value>
class IteratorBase
{
   public:
    virtual Value         operator*() const                     = 0;
    virtual IteratorBase& operator++()                          = 0;
    virtual bool          operator!=(IteratorBase const&) const = 0;
    virtual bool          operator==(IteratorBase const&) const = 0;

    // We need this function for making copies of the iterator
    virtual IteratorBase* clone() const = 0;
    virtual ~IteratorBase()             = default;
};
```

**Concrete class implementing `IteratorBase`.** This class implements the behavior defined in `IteratorBase`. The iterator it contains is the *actual* iterator returned by the collection you're iterating over. In your case, it'd be either `std::vector::iterator` or `std::vector::reverse_iterator`.

```
template <class Iter, class Value>
class IteratorDerived : public IteratorBase<Value>
{
    Iter it;

   public:
    IteratorDerived() = default;
    IteratorDerived(Iter it) : it(it) {}
    IteratorDerived(IteratorDerived const&) = default;
    IteratorDerived(IteratorDerived&&)      = default;

    Value                operator*() const override { return *it; }
    IteratorBase<Value>& operator++() override
    {
        ++it;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator!=(IteratorBase<Value> const& other) const override
    {
        auto* derived = dynamic_cast<IteratorDerived const*>(&other);
        return derived == nullptr || it != derived->it;
    }
    bool operator==(IteratorBase<Value> const& other) const override
    {
        auto* derived = dynamic_cast<IteratorDerived const*>(&other);
        return derived != nullptr && it == derived->it;
    }
    IteratorBase<Value>* clone() const override
    {
        return new IteratorDerived(*this);
    }
};
```

**`GenericIterator` implementation.** This is the actual implementation of `GenericIterator`, based on `IteratorBase` and `IteratorDerived`. Any iterator given to `GenericIterator` is wrapped in the corresponding `IteratorDerived`, which is then assigned to the `IteratorBase` pointer.

```
template <class Value>
class GenericIterator
{
    std::unique_ptr<IteratorBase<Value>> iterator;

   public:
    using value_type = typename std::remove_reference<Value>::type; 
    using reference = Value;

    GenericIterator() = default;
    GenericIterator(GenericIterator const& it) : iterator(it.iterator->clone())
    {
    }
    GenericIterator(GenericIterator&&) = default;

    // Creates a GenericIterator from an IteratorBase
    explicit GenericIterator(IteratorBase<Value> const& it)
      : iterator(it.clone())
    {
    }

    // Creates a GenericIterator from an IteratorDerived
    template <class Iter>
    explicit GenericIterator(IteratorDerived<Iter, Value> const& it)
      : iterator(it.clone())
    {
    }

    // Creates a GenericIterator by wrapping another Iter
    template <class Iter>
    GenericIterator(Iter it) : iterator(new IteratorDerived<Iter, Value>(it))
    {
    }

    GenericIterator& operator=(GenericIterator const& it)
    {
        iterator = std::unique_ptr<IteratorBase<Value>>(it.iterator->clone());
        return *this;
    }
    GenericIterator& operator=(GenericIterator&&) = default;

    Value            operator*() const { return *(*iterator); }
    GenericIterator& operator++()
    {
        ++(*iterator);
        return *this;
    }
    void operator++(int) {
        ++(*iterator);
    }

    bool operator==(GenericIterator const& other) const
    {
        return *iterator == *other.iterator;
    }
    bool operator!=(GenericIterator const& other) const
    {
        return *iterator != *other.iterator;
    }
};
```